# Why does IE leak memory when wrapping an HTML response in a jQuery object?

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, memory-leaks

I'm trying to figure out why IE is leaking memory when wrapping an AJAX-ly requested HTML page in a jQuery object for processing. The user may visit the page and let it sit for many minutes or hours, so the page uses jQuery's `ajax` method a few times a minute to get new data, and then I replace important parts of the page with the new pre-rendered data.

At this point, I've narrowed it down to a single call - when `$(data)` is invoked to wrap the HTML string, memory spikes a little, and doesn't ever seem to be garbage collected. Over time many hundreds of MB are used and I'm forced to reload the page or restart IE.

[**This fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/t8GzG/5/) is able to reproduce the issue. It uses AJAX to request a page, and then calls `$(data)` in a tight loop in order to exaggerate the leak. Chrome and Firefox both seem to react as I'd expect (memory is reclaimed), but IE is behaving badly. Surprise.

Using Process Explorer, I see memory consumption spike dramatically after running the above fiddle just two times.

[image]

I'm currently using IE9 in standards mode.

Why is this happening? Is there a workaround?

### Update

Here's a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/t8GzG/13/) that demonstrates the issue without using AJAX.

Comment: I see the memory increase, but it gets released shortly after. even increasing to 10000 iterations has the same result.

Comment: @KevinB I believe you tested it under IE10 standards because I did the same and saw the resources being released, however as Pwninstein mentions on IE9 is a totally different story, I did it once and saw my resources going from 50MB to 350MB and staying there...

Comment: I don't have IE10 on this machine. Windows 7 IE9

Comment: @KevinB what browser/OS? I can repro it with the fiddle with Win7 (x64) + IE9.0.8112 (x86)

Comment: I do see the leak. Lets narrow this down a bit though. If you simply use <div>foobar</div>, there's no leak. We need to narrow down to exactly what is causing it, factor out the ajax request.

Comment: According to the answer from MrLeap and a little research I believe you might be suffering from circular references memory leak, here is some information on it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd361842%28v=vs.85%29.aspx I know it says IE8 but it might help you to find a solution for your problem.

Comment: Thanks Xtian, I'll take a look at that. See my comment on MrLeap's answer. KevinB - see my question for a new AJAX-less fiddle that still reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I've found a workaround the the problem I described above.

In troubleshooting this, I tried a variety of things to prevent the leak from happening. The solution that I came up with was to ditch using `$.ajax` to retrieve the data and `$()` to wrap the results. Instead I used `$('#destination').load('sourceUrl #selector')` (see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)) to shove the data into a hidden div and then manipulate the result that way.

Turns out `$.load` uses `$.parseHTML` under the covers to manipulate the results and shove them in the specified location (and `$()` apparently doesn't). [See here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/ajax.js#L176) for source line.

- `$(htmlText)` leaks
- `$(bodyText)` doesn't leak
- `$.parseHtml(htmlText)` slowly leaks(?)
- `$.parseHtml(bodyText)` doesn't leak

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t8GzG/21/) to demonstrate.

I don't know *why* it behaves the way it does, but the short of it seems to be: avoid parsing full HTML documents whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing what you were seeing, when I changed the code to reallocate the function each time success gets called, magically it didn't leak (atleast in my environment.)

So, my solution is stupid, but it appears to work for me. Does it work for you?

```
$(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    $('#go').click(performCall);
});

function performCall() {
    $('#timestamp').text('Working...');

    $.ajax({
       url: 'http://fiddle.jshell.net/',
        success: function(){
            var func = function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $('#timestamp').text('Done at ' + new Date());
                for(var x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
                    var $a = $(data);
                }
            };
            func();
        }
   });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tCvUw/

Comment: Thanks, MrLeap. I tried it, and I saw what you described (no leak), but it looks like `data` is coming back as undefined, so `$(data)` doesn't do anything. Moving data, textStatus, and jqXHR to the anonymous 'success' function definition makes it work, but it's still leaky as before.

Comment: Yep, I see that now too. Derp. I'll keep looking at it.

Comment: No problem - I appreciate the new sets of eyes on the problem :) See my updated answer for a non-AJAX fiddle.