# My setTimeout doesn't respect the delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I want to repeat a function every 10s with setTimeout. My function is:

```
dateInLive = function() {
    crono = function(){
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.datePoste').each(function(){
                $(this).load('in_live.php','in_live='+$(this).attr('id'))
            });
        crono();
        }
        ,10000);
    }
    crono();
}
```

But, it's really random; sometimes it's repeating after 15s, sometimes after 3s, sometimes after 6s.

Comment: It looks like you're accidentally called crono() twice. Tried removing the crono() call from inside the setTimeout?

Comment: Looks like you'll benefit more using `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()`.

Comment: @user125697 No, he is calling it within a `setTimeout()` to repeat the function. It is better to use `setInteral()` instead.

Comment: @Antony Why not use setInterval in that case??

Comment: And how long does all the ajax functions inside the loop take to complete ?

Comment: Swings and roundabouts, regarding `setInterval` and `setTimeout`.  However, the call to `crono()` inside the timeout should be in the load callback.

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan first place I wanted to use setInterval() but I read a lot about how setTimeout is better

Comment: Does'nt matter, the loop will complete in 0.00003 milliseconds as load() is async, and crono will be called right away, so using an interval has no real apparent advantage.

Comment: @GradislavaBikkulova First, you should use `setInterval()` in this case. Second, it is up to the browser to decide when to call a function again. Setting it to `10000` does not guarantee that it will be executed every 10 seconds. Here's my [little app](http://laucheukhim.github.com/frame-rate-distribution/) that test the actual time it takes to run a `setInterval()`.

Comment: Ajax requests take some time to complete. More than likely all of those .loads you are performing aren't finishing in the allowed 10 seconds. setTimeout is the appropriate method to use in this case, however the method should only be restarted AFTER all ajax requests are complete to avoid queuing up 30-40 ajax requests at once on a slow network.

Comment: I think that this is definitely a case where `setTimeout()` is better than `setInterval()`, though not the way it's used here. Starting HTTP requests at intervals is kind-of risky because there's no way to ensure that they're finishing. It'd be more robust to account for possible long delays by resetting the timer after the HTTP requests have completed (taking into account elapsed time).

Comment: Whatever anyone else says, do *not* use `setInterval` instead. There are very good reasons never to use `setInterval`, as described [here](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#other.timeouts).

Comment: @Spudley Maybe it is because of the exact reason why `setTimeout` prevents stacking that causes a random repeating interval?

Comment: @Antony -- if you've got something blocking JS, the interval will  be incorrect for both `setTimeout` and `setInterval` methods; neither of them guarantees a perfectly regular firing of the event because JS is not threaded. But the effect is worse with `setInterval`, because if you get a bunch of stacked events queued up, they'll all fire at once when the block is lifted. This is very rarely what is intended, especially when the regular event is an ajax event as in this case, because that itself can cause further blocking and complicate things further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall `crono()` only when all the ajax requests are completed :

```
function crono(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        var arr = [];
        $('.datePoste').each(function(){
            var self = this;
                xhr = $.get('in_live.php', {in_live : this.id}, function(data) {
                    $(self).html( $.parseHTML(data) );
                });
            arr.push(xhr);
        });
        $.when.apply($, arr).done(crono);
    }, 10000);
}
```

Comment: Ah, i didn't see your answer before i posted mine. One issue though, i don't think .load returns an xhr, i may be wrong though. I'm pretty sure the promise object returned from .promise is for the animation queue when used this way, not the ajax requests.

Comment: @KevinB - was'nt sure about load either, but all the other ajax methods returns a promise, just can't find anything on load() ?

Comment: well, since .load returns a jQuery collection, that's where i'm basing my thoughts off of. using .promise() (which is what .when does) on a jQuery collection gets a promise object that resolves when all existing animations are complete. I don't have an easy way of testing this at the moment.

Comment: @KevinB - I'm pretty sure you're right about `load()` not returning promises, so I'll just change it to `$.get`, as there does'nt seem to be any filtering going on.

Comment: That's better, but i have one more nitpick :) Since you're using `$.get()`, you have to use `.html` which appears to cause a memory leak in IE9 on whole html documents. (ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416869/why-does-ie-leak-memory-when-wrapping-an-html-response-in-a-jquery-object) using `$.parseHTML()` first should fix it. I suspect `dataType: "html"` (or `$.get(... ,"html)`) would fix it too.

Comment: @KevinB - did'nt know that, and can't say I've ever had that issue, but if it is in fact a known issue, I guess it's better to be safe then sorry. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're using `setTimeout` to run a repeated event.

This is correct (others have recommended `setInterval` instead, but there are issues with this).

However you aren't setting the timeout on the subsequent calls -- you're just calling the `crono()` function directly, so after the initial timeout delay, it will then just start calling itself immediately over and over and over forever (until it exhausts the stack space).

What you need to do is call `setTimeout()` each time you call the function. Recode it something like this:

```
dateInLive = function() {
    crono = function(){
        $('.datePoste').each(function(){
            $(this).load('in_live.php','in_live='+$(this).attr('id'))
        });
        setTimeout(crono,10000);
    }
    setTimeout(crono,10000);
}
```

Comment: Does'nt look like that's the issue to me. The timeout is inside the function, and the function is only called again inside that timeout.

Comment: It might be nice to use function declaration syntax too.

Comment: i still have the same issue

Answer (score 2):

In this situation, i would use deferred objects.

```
function crono(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        var defArr = [];
        $('.datePoste').each(function(i,el){
            var deferred = $.Deferred();
            defArr.push(deferred.promise());
            $(this).load('in_live.php','in_live='+$(this).attr('id'), function() {
                 deferred.resolve();
            });
        });
        $.when.apply($,defArr).done(crono);
    }, 10000);
}
```

Doing it this way will request all sections, then when all sections are received, wait 10 seconds and request them again, avoiding the request from piling up in a slow network situation.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing something before creating the new timeout, which means there is bound to be "some" delay.

have a look at the [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) function.

Answer (score 0):

You just have the `crono()` function in the wrong place.

```
dateInLive = function() {
 crono = function(){
 setTimeout(function() {
        crono();
        $('.datePoste').each(function(){
               $(this).load('in_live.php','in_live='+$(this).attr('id'))
           });
        }
        ,10000);
    }

}
```