# JQuery find() assignment causing high memory consumption (IE.11 & Firefox) not Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, memory-leaks, selector

I have had a solid search on the forum and can't find an answer to the issue I'm currently experiencing.

Thanks in advance for any advice received.

I'm experiencing an issue with HIGH memory consumption when using Firefox (49.02) and IE.11.

I have an application that uses `setTimeout` to trigger an AJAX call which in turn triggers a custom event handler attached to a Context object. passing through the returned data into a utility update method. `setTimeout` is removed and then reset with the desired time portion usually every 20 seconds.

1. The returned document is quite large perhaps 5/10 mb depending on the client data.

Within an isolated handler method the data is passed in as a parameter. We assign the data representation of an HTML template. to a local variable

```
1. var contentTemplate = data.content; (returned from an AJAX call)
```

We then use find to locate and assign a section of the document as a **JQuery** object

```
var body = $(contentTemplate).find("#maincontent");
```

After each iteration of set timeout the handler method is called again with a new AJAX data object passed in and the assignment begins again.

After each iterations of the last assignment memory increases until it the browser hits its memory limit.

commenting out

```
var body = $(contentTemplate).find("#maincontent");
```

And the high consumption stops. There is no leaks in any other part of the application no circular references or closure issues.

As a test in the handler method I created a big data structure and assigned it to a local variable. No increase in memory usage was observed. Well a bit but it was reclaimed by GC very quickly.

```
var a = new Array(100000).join('azazazazazaza');
```

I've tried using empty and remove on the selector but nothing works.

I understand `.html()` when assigning a variable, JQuery manages its internal cache.

We can’t do the following expression

```
var body = $(contentTemplate).find("#maincontent").html();
```

Does anyone have any ideas what the issue is here. JQuery is def cashing the selector somehow. Looking on the DOM the nodes keep increasing after each iteration but are not viewable on the page only the last assigned set.

I could write a some plain JavaScript to parse over the template and pull out the area of the doc I need but I would rather use JQuery as its used through out the rest of the script.

I'm prob. missing something stupid here but I've exhausted all channels.

Thanks

Comment: I unfortunately do not have an answer for you but I am interested in what the answer ends up being! I take it you have determined that it is the `find` and not jquery html parsing `$()` part of the operation that is causing the leak?

Comment: I'm certain it's find causing the issue, writing the selector using the following notation var contentTemplate = $(data.content).find("#maincontent").html(); still causes the leak. I'll keep digging until I get the answer then I'll post it back up. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Excuse my last post. Your right, just wrapping the returned data in a selector will cause the issue

Comment: It looks like this person encountered the same issue then - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416869/why-does-ie-leak-memory-when-wrapping-an-html-response-in-a-jquery-object they never found a perfect answer but they did find a work around!

Comment: Thanks I'll read this now.